How to remove "Enter your email address popup" automatically in PowerBI
I am receiving a popup for "Enter your email address" in my PowerBI report. How can we remove this popup or get it cancelled via an automated way utilizing PowerShell or python coding.

Note - We have tried to obtain processname by running following PowerShell code before and after the popup is received, but we are unable to find a distinct process.
cls
#Get-Process | Sort-Object -Property Id #28552
$x=Get-process
$y= $x.processname
WRITE-HOST "Sleep"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 75

$x=Get-process
$y1= $x.processname
$y | Where-Object {$_ -notin $y1}


You're getting the popup because you're not signed-in to the Power BI service - it says so right there in the Infobar message below the ribbon.

"We have tried to obtain processname by running following PowerShell code before and after the popup is received, but we are unable to find a distinct process." - What makes you think the popup is in its own process? (Hint: it isn't).

Have you tried changing the sensitivity label to prevent the pop-up?
